# Copy and Paste Google Sheet script not copying full range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

I'm using the following script in order to copy data from one sheet to another in the same spreadsheet with values only and in a specific cell.

My problem is that the range to copy had to be updated by 2 more columns but now the script is not correctly working. When I check the sheet where the values are copied, I'm missing the 2 new columns somehow. I already make sure that the range specified in the code is the one I want.

I would really appreaciate your help.
Thank you!!

```
function copyANDpaste() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var originSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
   var listToCopy = originSheet.getRange('B9:AN26');
   var destinationSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('1st Week');
   var destinationColum = destinationSheet.getLastColumn();
   listToCopy.copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange('B2'),{contentsOnly:true});
};
```

Comment: The script works fine on my spreadsheet. I think the problem is not within this code. Perhaps you keep running the previous version of your function. Look at ALL your code more closely

Comment: What do you mean? That is actually all the code. I'm just trying a simple copy paste but it became somehow tricky to solve by myself.
I checked and I'm running the last updated version of my function

Comment: Maybe check the exact spelling of "1st Week" (uppercase, space). By the way, you don't use `destinationColum` take a look at it!

Comment: Please add more details about the source / target sheets and ranges. (Does the source or target ranges have merged cells? )

Comment: Yes they do have merges cells. Also, spelling has been checked and is not the issue.

I'm trying to make a library in order to work witht he script in different sheets but I'm unable to use it since it cant open the library in another window

Comment: Please, make a copy of your spreadsheet, remove all sensitive data, an share it. I'm sure there is some plain error or a typo in data or somewhere else. The code is more or less fine by itself.

Comment: Could you reword "had to be updated by 2 more columns" to explain it better?